# Why doesn't my windows environment properly install external C++ libraries?

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, msys2, vcpkg

## Description

Hi everyone, I'm new to C++ have having difficulty working with external libraries:

I'm currently running on Windows 10 and trying to install a library like libcurl on my machine. I have installed it using both msys2 and vcpkg. When compiling code using g++ and including curl, the #include cannot be found as the linked library isn't found by my compiler.

I'm also not really sure where the library was installed to.

## Msys2 installation:

```
**pacman -Sy mingw-w64-x86_64-curl**

 mingw32 is up to date
 mingw64 is up to date
 ucrt64 is up to date
 clang32 is up to date
 clang64 is up to date
 msys is up to date
warning: mingw-w64-x86_64-curl-7.86.0-5 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) mingw-w64-x86_64-curl-7.86.0-5

Total Installed Size:  3.07 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] y
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                               [###############################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                             [###############################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                  [###############################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                            [###############################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                          [###############################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) reinstalling mingw-w64-x86_64-curl                     [###############################] 100%


**pkg-config --cflags libcurl**

Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'libcurl', required by 'virtual:world', not found

**pkg-config --libs libcurl**

Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'libcurl', required by 'virtual:world', not found
```

## Vcpkg installation:

```
**vcpkg install curl:x64-windows**

The following packages are already installed:
    curl[core,non-http,schannel,ssl,sspi]:x64-windows -> 7.84.0#2
curl:x64-windows is already installed
Restored 0 package(s) from C:\Users\Joseph Kan\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 533.8 us. Use --debug to see more details.
Total install time: 1.645 ms
curl provides CMake targets:

    # this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct
    find_package(CURL CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE CURL::libcurl)
```

## G++ Compilation:

```
**g++ -o sample sample.cpp sampleInterface.cpp -lcurl**

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Because it's Microsoft.  My recommendation is to avoid Microsoft whenever possible.  I understand Windows is a necessary evil.  But when it comes to apps, there are much better alternatives.  What do you use to compile your C++ apps?

Comment: You need to tell your compiler/linker where the library is located using the `-L` option

Comment: Installing packages multiple times using different package managers sounds like a recipe for confusion. You should try to understand your errors, not try random stuff hoping that it might work.

Comment: `mingw-w64-x86_64-curl` ... `mingw32 is up to date` ... `mingw64 is up to date` ... `mingw32/bin/ld.exe` - mingw32 looks a bit suspicious here. maybe you install x64 library and are trying to link it with 32-bit toolset?

Comment: Mingw on windows is a recipe for troubles. I've yet to find a person who doesn't have troubles with it. Looks like you already have msvc installed, why not use it? Don't forget `vcpkg integrate install`.

Comment: MSYS2 has different compiler toolchains available and people get into trouble by extremely often by not using the right one.  Be sure to start your MSYS2 shell using mingw64.exe or the equivalent start menu shortcut.  Do not attempt to use the MinGW toolchain in `C:/mingw`: that is some separate thing that is not part of MSYS2; it won't know how to find MSYS2 libraries and might use the wrong architecture.  Use the 64-bit toolchain MSYS2 provides (`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`).  If you still have trouble, type `which g++` and show us the output.

Comment: @Osyotr You've met one now. :P

Comment: Why are using non-MSYS2 GCC?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:
Wrong triplet. The `x64-windows` is the MSVC triplet.
Your probably want `x64-mingw-dynamic`

Furthermore:
To get pkg-config working with vcpkg you need to setup `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to e.g.

```
<VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR>/lib/pkgconfig
```

vcpkg won't be magically added to the search paths for pkg-config without that....